# How many ways to order $5$ people with different heights in one line, but with a requirement.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Requirement: there is no $3$ people with height going up. (example: if we have $5$ people with these heights : $1.1$,$1.2$,$1.3$,$1.4$,$1.5$. 
We can't have an order like this $1.5 , 1.4 , 1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3$ because there's $3$ people with their height going up $1.1 \to 1.2 \to 1.3$. (I hope I explained it clearly). 
I used the inclusion exclusion principle, each time choosing $3,4,5$ out of $5$ people to be in the order. 
while $5!$ is the number of ways to order them without any requirement. 
I got the answer to be: $5!$ - $5 \choose 3$ $3 \cdot 2$ + $5 \choose 4$$2$ $-1=69$. 

explanation for $3$: I tried to look at the $3$ people I'm choosing as "one" person, so I had $3$ people to order. 
For $4$: same as $3$ but this time I chose $4$ people so I had $2$ people to order so multiplied by $2$.
I would be happy for any feedback about my solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: A [quick script](https://tio.run/##XY67CgIxEEX7fMUUW2RRA4vY6VaWdltYqEjQuDuYF8ksRn8@JthZzeHCPXcmGZ9K65zReBcI9pKkOGAk9h@IwWskxrSzo4p0lfGm7B3tCCnCDoxMaGYDTSEPnC@6VmhlR5raksXaPU7KAj/ztIR3C6seEvSVGvigr5YGSKIuxIxEW6R@poFC7U/uVc5PWOCBmlQoM9t1mfn/qCq9CmYmSehshFMnxOaS8xc "Haskell – Try It Online") I wrote in Haskell tells me the answer is 70, though it's possible my code is erroneous.

Comment: [Same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029088/in-how-many-ways-can-5-students/4029098#4029098) was asked today.

Comment: Your working is fine except the last subtraction $-1$ should not be there as those were subtracted $2$ times and added $1$ time which is already correct.